# Running Debian Lenny installer in Xen DomU

Tags: virtualization, debian, xen, debian-lenny

I've successfully managed to boot Debian installer (supplied the installation disc's initrd.gz); however, it is unable to mount the CD image itself, although I have enabled it in the DomU configuration like this:

```
disk = [
            'phy:/dev/sda5,sda1,w',
            'phy:/dev/sda6,sda2,w',
            'file:/root/debian-504-amd64-netinst.iso,hdc:cdrom,r'
       ]
```

Using the installer's shell I can read the /dev/hdc (which pretends to be the CD drive); however, mounting it fails with:

```
mount: mounting /dev/hdc on /mnt/ failed: No such file or directory
```

Dom0 is also Debian Lenny; Xen's version is 3.2.1. Any ideas?

Comment: does `/mnt` exist ?

Comment: Of course it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this counts as an answer, but we just switched to VirtualBox for this task :)

Answer (score 0):

why not use xen-create-image

```
sudo xen-create-image --accounts --gateway=xx.xx.xx.xx --netmask=yy.yy.yy.yy --ip=zz.zz.zz.zz --lvm=yourlvmlabel --hostname=yourhostname
```

put some sane defaults in

```
 /etc/xen-tools/xen-tools.conf
```

find more info on: http://www.xen-tools.org/software/xen-tools/

Comment: that´s of course if you have xen-tools installed via "sudo apt-get install xen-tools" ;)

Comment: installing xen-tools manually is a really simple task.

Comment: The problem is that we need to teach students installing Debian; at the same time, we have no spare computers that can be completely be given into their possession. That's why we use Xen, and that's why we need to make the installer work, not just provide them debootstrapped systems.